# Multiplying a matrix by a vector of scalars in parallel C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, parallel-processing, iterator

I have two dictionaries of arrays that are multiplied together and stored in a dictionary of Strings and int[]. The code works

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = {1,0,3,4,0};
        int[] b = { 3, 0, 9, 10, 0};
        int[] c = {2,3,3,5,0};
        var ret = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
        ret.Add("Jack", a);
        ret.Add("Jane", b);
        ret.Add("James", c);

        var multipliers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        multipliers.Add("Jack", 2);
        multipliers.Add("Jane", 3);
        multipliers.Add("James", 5);

        var results = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

        foreach (var item in ret)
        {
            int[] arr= new int[item.Value.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Length; i ++)
            {
                int d = item.Value[i] * multipliers[item.Key];

                arr[i] = d;
            }
            results.Add(item.Key,arr);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? Is there a way to do this in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet is the way to do it in parallel:

```
var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int[]>();

Parallel.ForEach(ret, pair =>
{
      var srcArr = pair.Value;
      var arr = new int[srcArr.Length];
      var multBy = multipliers[pair.Key];

      for (var i = 0; i < srcArr.Length; i++)
      {
           var d = srcArr[i] * multBy;

           arr[i] = d;
      }
      results[pair.Key] = arr;
});
```

Comment: I am guessing this  require a BackgroundWorker and is thread safe?

Comment: @ccsv it doesn't requires `BackgroundWorker` and the `ConcurrentDictionary` keep it thread safe.